# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-multidex

I'm facing the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

My App **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ahija.com"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 24
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    configurations.all {
//        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
//            def requested = details.requested
//            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
//                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
//                    details.useVersion '26.1.0'
//                }
//            }
//        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

//    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
//        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
//    })

    // GOOGLE
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'

    // PLAY SERVICES
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'

    // FIREBASE
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0'

    // FACEBOOK
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'

    // OTHERS
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.bottomnavigation:bottom-navigation:2.0.1-rc1'
    compile 'com.github.zurche:open-weather-map-android-wrapper:v0.1'
    compile 'com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'de.cketti.mailto:email-intent-builder:1.0.0'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.jrvansuita:PickImage:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.github.DamanSingh4321:ProProgressViews:v1.1'
    compile group: 'com.cloudinary', name: 'cloudinary-android', version: '1.20.0'

    // INTEGRATIONS
    compile 'com.github.freshdesk:hotline-android:1.2.5'

    // NEW AND COOL
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
//    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
//    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'

    // ANNOTATION PROCESSORS
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
//    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'

    // TEST
//    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

If I try to build the app, it builds just fine and I get the APKs but if I try to run from Android Studio directly on my device, I get the above error.
How to fix it?

I am facing this error since a long time. I am currently testing by debug versions by manually building the apk and then transferring it to the phone.
The "run" button directly gives me the above error.

Comment: Please tell me you found where the error is from... I've got the same problem ...

Answer (score 0):

add manifest in application tag

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Comment: didn't help at all

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have compatibility issue in your dependencies, which are `Firebase/Google Play Service` and `FirebaseUI`. From [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) you can see the following note:

> Each version of FirebaseUI has dependency on a fixed version of these libraries, defined as the variable firebase_version in common/constants.gradle. If you are using any dependencies in your app of the form compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-*:x.y.z' or compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-*:x.y.z' you need to make sure that you use the same version that your chosen version of FirebaseUI requires.
>
> For convenience, here are some recent examples:
>
> ```
> +--------------------+--------------------------------+
> | FirebaseUI Version | Firebase/Play Services Version |
> +--------------------+--------------------------------+
> |              3.0.0 | 11.4.2                         |
> |              2.4.0 | 11.4.0                         |
> |              2.3.0 | 11.0.4                         |
> |              2.2.0 | 11.0.4                         |
> |              2.1.1 | 11.0.2                         |
> |              2.0.1 | 11.0.1                         |
> |              1.2.0 | 10.2.0                         |
> |              1.1.1 | 10.0.0 or 10.0.1               |
> |              1.0.0 | 9.8.0                          |
> +--------------------+--------------------------------+
> ```

Because you use Firebase /Play service `11.4.0` you need to use FirebaseUI `2.4.0`:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.4.0'
```

Read more about the same problem in FirebaseUI issue: [UI incompatibility with other Firebase libs is not warned in documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/218)

Comment: I did this but it didn't help. See my updated gradle code

Comment: Have you add `classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'`?